# How to display manually the return Input::all() in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

The Code of my controller:

```
public function show()
{

    return Input::all();

}
```

And the result is:
`{"_token":"TmwBJ0us217sqXYvfzVdbAYiC8k85OsLriUgl3HK","date_from":"01\/30\/17","date_to":"01\/31\/2017"}`

How can I display it manually?
My not working code is:
`$dateto = {{Input::get('date_to')}};`

Comment: Why don't you use `Request` instead. for example: `$dateto = request('date_to');`

Answer (score 0):

You should try this way:

```
$dateto = Input::get('date_to');
echo $dateto;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I've fix it already. I use ->with so that I can add some stuff and design on my page. short code for the controller

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Request` instead of `Input`. Read more here for [Laravel 5.4](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#retrieving-input), [Laravel 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#retrieving-input).

And this is the code you want to have:

```
$dateto = request('date_to');
```

Answer (score 0):

Same result could be get by `request()` helper.

```
$dateTo = request()->get('date_to');
```

But the convenient way would be to assign all at once and access them one by one when needed.

```
$request = request()->all();
$dateTo = $request['date_to'];
```